# Set the active link styles when using a hash or url fragment?

Tags: html, css

Doesn't the active link show the styles of the current page? I'm trying to apply a style on the active page but it's not working. I'm using a url hash or url fragment.

When using a single page application you may have:

- /mypage.html#home
- /mypage.html#products
- /mypage.html#services
- /mypage.html#about

If a link is active I want the selected page to have an red underline under it.

```css
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

#menubar > a {
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#menubar > a:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #585858;
}

#menubar > a:active {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <a id="Home" href="#home">
   <span>Home</span>
  </a>
  <a id="Products" href="#products">
   <span>Products</span>
  </a>
  <a id="Services" href="#services">
   <span>Services</span>
  </a>
  <a id="About" href="#about">
   <span>About</span>
  </a>
  <a id="Contact" href="#contact">
   <span>Contact</span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target):

```
:target {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

> The :target CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target
>   element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

Comment: Try lowercasing your ID names